# Return one result from Json String in PHP

Tags: php, getjson, json

hi im trying to return 1 set of array from a json string in my code from searching nas i would like to show the data associated with that name.
Any suggestions would be great .. thanks

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//echo $_GET['urlname'];

$json_string =    file_get_contents("http://192.168.1.104/testing_JSON/newjson.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json['contacts'];

for(var i = 0; i < $parsed_json.length; i++)
{
if($parsed_json[i].$parsed_json.name == 'nas')
{
 return $parsed_json[i].$parsed_json.name;
}
}
?
```

im getting a white screen with the above code.

thanks

Comment: You didn't showed any JSON string in your question. `192.168.1.104` is something different for most of us. Keep in mind, that we're not in the same local area network as you are. also try to create a self-contained example.

Comment: you are trying to use javascript syntax here. rtfm http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php http://www.php.net/count

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo` instead of `return`. Return doesn't print anything.

Comment: thanks for reply .. didnt work still white screen

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the white screen. Error referenced.

Comment: I think you're confusing PHP with Javascript. `length` is not a function. Use `count($parsed_json)` instead.

Also I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this `$parsed_json[i].$parsed_json.name`.

Comment: php is new to me im just learning.. any suggestions. the count($parsed) didnt work